# ASP Classic SQL Server XML format with Stored Procedure and Parameters

Tags: sql-server, xml, asp-classic

I'm trying to modify the routine suggested by John [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927628/asp-classic-sql-server-return-results-from-database-in-xml-format), actually I did not changed anything, I just added a parameter, but I get

```
ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, 
or are in conflict with one another.

/test/test_xml.asp, line 19
```

where line 19 contains:

```
ocmd.Parameters.Append paramTotals
```

I tried also in other way, like

```
ocmd.Parameters("@ID").value=1030
```

but I get following error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e21'   
Procedure or function 'spTEST_XML' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.
/test/test_xml.asp, line 20
```

where in line 20 there is

```
oCmd.Execute , , 1025
```

> While, if I remove the parameter it works perfectly....

here the full routine

```
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;server=TEST;Database=test;User ID=sa;Password=test"
oCmd.Properties("Output Stream") = oXML
oXml.async = false
oCmd.CommandText = "spTEST_XML"
ocmd.CommandType=4
Set paramTotals = ocmd.CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , 1030)
ocmd.Parameters.Append paramTotals
oCmd.Execute , , 1025
Response.ContentType="text/xml"
Response.Write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>")
Response.Write oXML.xml 
Set oXML = Nothing
Set oCmd = Nothing
```

while here the top of the StoredProcedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTEST_XML]
(
    @ID     int
)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @SDT datetime = sysdatetime()


if @ID is null 
    begin
        update dbo.PayPal set downloaded=@SDT where Validation='VERIFIED' AND downloaded is null
    end
else
    begin
        update dbo.PayPal set downloaded=@SDT where Validation='VERIFIED' AND ID>=@ID
    end

select
    payment.id reference_id,
    payment.SMSRN SellingManagerSalesRecordNumber,
    cast(dateadd(hh,2,payment.payment_date) as date) payment_date_CET, 
    payment.receiver_email, 
    payment.auction_buyer_id,   
    payment.payer_email, 
    format(payment.mc_gross/XC,'N2') Payment_EUR, 
    format(payment.mc_fee/XC,'N2') Fees_EUR, 
    format((payment.mc_gross-payment.mc_fee)/xc,'N2') Net_EUR,
    format(payment.mc_handling/xc,'N2') Handling_EUR, 
    format(payment.mc_shipping/xc,'N2') Shipping_EUR, 
    payment.payment_status, 
    payment.num_cart_items,
    payment.memo,
    payment.case_id, 
    payment.mc_currency,
    payment.mc_gross,
    payment.mc_fee, 
    payment.mc_handling,
    payment.mc_shipping,
    payment.payment_date
from
(
    select distinct
        p.id,p.payment_date, p.auction_buyer_id, p.mc_currency, p.mc_gross, p.mc_fee, p.payer_email, p.receiver_email, s.sellingmanagersalesrecordnumber SMSRN,
        coalesce(p.mc_handling,0) mc_handling, p.mc_shipping, p.payment_status, 
        p.num_cart_items, p.memo, p.case_id, p.case_type, p.case_creation_date, 
        p.case_closed,
        coalesce(CAST ((Select top (1) rate from dbo.EurRates r where r.Currency=p.mc_currency and r.FXDate<=p.payment_date) as Decimal (10,4)),1) XC
    from dbo.PayPal p
    left join dbo.eBaySales s   on s.referenceID=p.txn_id
    where p.Validation='VERIFIED'
    and p.downloaded=@SDT
) as Payment
order by receiver_email asc, payment_date desc
FOR XML AUTO , ROOT ('PaymentsArray') , ELEMENTS
```

END

Comment: `While, if I remove the parameter it works perfectly....` What's the question then?

Comment: if I remove the 2 lines with `Set paramTotals = ocmd.CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , 1030)
ocmd.Parameters.Append paramTotals` the routine works, but I need to add a parameter to the procedure, but I got that error and I do not understand why: my knowledge are basic but it is not the first stored procedure I build, although is the first with `for xml` as output.

Comment: do you have definitions for the ADO constant adInteger? This can usually be found in an include file adovbs.inc.

Comment: @JoshMontgomery Yes, I have, but I've tried also replacing with adInteger value (3), and adParamInput with (1) but result is the same

Comment: I see. It would be nice too see rest of the procedure's DDL code? Modification may be needed.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin just added the latest version of SP - Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SP seems OK, no need to modify, it's XML compliant.

However the value `1025` you passed Execute method as `options` parameter corresponds to `adCmdText + adExecuteStream` is not suitable for your command.

Instead, it must be `adCmdStoredProc + adExecuteStream` which equals to `1028`.

So, the following code should work for you.

```vb
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
Set oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCmd.ActiveConnection = "Provider=sqloledb;server=TEST;Database=test;User ID=sa;Password=test"
oCmd.Properties("Output Stream") = oXML
oXml.async = false
oCmd.CommandText = "spTEST_XML"
ocmd.CommandType= 4
Set paramTotals = ocmd.CreateParameter("@ID", adInteger, adParamInput, , 0)
ocmd.Parameters.Append paramTotals
oCmd.Execute , , 4 + 1024 ' adCmdStoredProc + adExecuteStream
Response.ContentType="text/xml"
Response.Write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>")
Response.Write oXML.xml 
Set oXML = Nothing
Set oCmd = Nothing
```

Comment: I see. Actually I tried to understand the meaning of that 1025 but did not found any info about ADODB.Command Execute Parameters.
I try immediately and let you know. Yess!, works like a charm!
Thanks!