# Variable when writing XML - Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have the below code, how would i replace the '1' within the below with a variable ?

```
Set objorderline1 = objXML.createElement("OrderLine")

Set objorderline1att = objXML.createAttribute("xmlns")

objorderline1att.text = ""

objorderline1.setAttributeNode objorderline1att

objorder.appendChild objorderline1
```

e.g.
Set objlinenumber(linenumber) = objXML.createElement("LineNumber")

```
objlinenumber(linenumber).text = linenumber

objorderline(linenumber).appendChild objlinenumber(linenumber)

Set objproduct(linenumber) = objXML.createElement("Product")
```

I want to be able to loop through a table of products from the database and create separate nodes for each product in the XML.

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about replacing the 1 in the object names with a variable? If so look at [`ExecuteGlobal` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/342311f1(v=vs.84)) for details of executing code as a string.

Comment: Something like this... Set Call ExecuteGlobal("objorderline" & linenumner & "end sub") = objXML.createElement("OrderLine")?

Comment: Syntax error, not that then :)

Comment: No `Set` you are not assigning an object reference. I would construct a string from the sample above concatenating the `linenumber` where needed then call `Call ExecuteGlobal(yourcodestring)`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that needing to do this is usually a sign that your code needs a refactor.  Can you [edit] the question and elaborate on the reason for needing to do this?

Comment: s = "objorderline" & linenumber

Set Call ExecuteGlobal(S) = objXML.createElement("OrderLine")

Comment: Look at the duplicate target for an example of how you use `ExecuteGlobal`. There is no `Set` or assignment so the line should have been `Call ExecuteGlobal(s)` if you have defined the code in the string variable `s` on another line.

Comment: Really sorry I dont get it - are we saying we no longer need the set at all. What is the set actually doing ?

Comment: I think it would help if you [edit] the question and explain why you need to do this and what are the reasons for it. It doesn't seem like you are very familiar with VBScript so suggesting you use `ExecuteGlobal` is probably not the best idea as it's a more advanced concept in VBScript and there are fundamentals you need to understand first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP Classic SQL Server return results from database in XML format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41927628)

Comment: As @user692942 suggests I think we are dealing with an xy problem here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem Explaining why you need this will possibly uncover the fact that you are actually looking for a way to define and call a function.

Comment: I've done it ! will update post with solution

Comment: @Emma please don't edit an answer into your question. Use the answer box below to post an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Building the string then adding that variable into the code works as expected. Quite a straight forward one but here is the solution.

```
s = "objorderline" & linenumber
t = "objorderlineatt" & linenumber
ln = "objlinenumber" & linenumber
pr = "objproduct" & linenumber


Set s = objXML.createElement("OrderLine")
    Set t = objXML.createAttribute("xmlns")
    t.text = ""
    s.setAttributeNode t
    objorder.appendChild s


    Set ln = objXML.createElement("LineNumber")
    ln.text = linenumber
    s.appendChild ln
    Set pr = objXML.createElement("Product")
```

Comment: Is this meant as an answer to your own question (which is perfectly fine)? In that case I would help if you added some explanation to your code to explain why it solves your problem. If not, you can delete this and edit your question to include more details.

Comment: I originally edited the question and someone above said to post it as an answer, seems like there is no winning.

Comment: If it is in fact an answer, then it's perfectly fine here, but it would be even better if you explained how this snippet of code solved your problem. Code-only answers are usually not that helpful.